# SharePoint 2013 - JWT - allowed claims

Tags: 2013, app, provider-hosted-app

I'm currently researching possibilities with on-premise high-trust provider apps in SharePoint 2013 in Java.

As for now ,I succeeded in authenticating user via JWT token with these claims:

`nii : urn:office:idp:activedirectory` and `nameid : <sid>`,

```
upn: <upn>
```

I know it should be possible to use also `smtp` claim with user email, but I'm wondering if this is also possible with `someaccountname` (domain\username) with something like passing user name as claim for AD authentication, eg: `i:0#.w|domain\username`?

I tried putting those into different claims, but it didn't work. Maybe someone alredy tried that and could share some information?

Comment: Try PPID field with the AD . I used PPID field passed from AD to authenticate to sharepoint.

Answer (score 2):

High Trust apps means that the app authenticates via certificates that have been added to/trusted by SharePoint. In a high-trust scenario, the app is responsible for setting the user identity under which the request should be processed.

The mechanics of setting the identity can be seen in the TokenHelper class that is part of the [App for SharePoint Web Toolkit](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AppForSharePointWebToolkit/).

Comment: I already know that. Actually I'm trying to integrate SharePoint with Java application. I was able to pass user identity with SID from AD, email address as smtp, but I wan't if it would be possible to pass simply user name in DOMAIN\Login format to make things simple.

Comment: You are using IDP or SP initiated approach ? how are you implementing this ,using saml ? try adding the claim in federatedMetadata.xml file like          <claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/email" optional="true" />
          <claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/name" optional="true" /> . A custom STS will allow you to send the claims you need.